# GitHub Permission Denied (Public Key)

Tags: ssh, github, rsa, key

I'm getting the following printout with the `-vT` command (as per github's troubleshooting)

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/someuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/github_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/github_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/someuser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

It was working properly as of yesterday.  Since then I have restarted the computer and I am now on a different network.  However it looks like the network is not the issue since i do establish a connection over port 22.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you try regenerating the key `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and adding the public key to github and trying?

Comment: When you do `ssh -T git@github.com` does it ask you a question?  If so, answer it and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but I ran into the same problem and ended up getting it working for myself so I thought I'd offer up what worked for me here.

When you clone, make sure you don't use the `http` URL.

Do this:

```
git clone git@github.com:foo/project-name.git
```

Not this:

```
git clone http://github.com/foo/project-name
```

I was originally cloning the `http` URL, which didn't allow my ssh credentials to take affect. I'm not sure this is your problem since you said it was working the day before, but it may give you something to try.

FYI - to get the URL of the current repo you have checked out, do this:

```
cd $REPO_DIR
git config --list | grep remote.origin.url
```

Comment: You can view and change the remote repo with the command git remote. You don't have to re-clone.